# How to handle successful fetch POST if we don't need to do anything else?

Tags: javascript, fetch

If I have a simple fetch request like this;

```
var body = JSON.stringify({
    "param1": Date.now(),
    "param2": "Some parameter"
})
fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Authorization": `Basic ${credentials}`,
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: body
            })
            .then(response => response.text())
            .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

and the response from the API will either be a 200 (Success) or not. Unless there is an error, I don't need to do anything with the response if it is successful so what can I do in the .then block of the fetch response? I tried just putting in;

```
.then(response)
```

but I get an error saying response not defined.

Even if I were to check and confirm that the response status is a 200 (i.e.: `response.status === "200"`), what should I put after that? I don't want to console.log it or anything. I really don't want to anything if successful. What should I do?

Maybe I'm not explaining myself well but I do run into this where I'm just posting to an API and if it's successful, I don't need to do anything else.

Comment: You can just omit the `.then()` if you don't need to do anything in it.

Comment: If you don't need to do anything, don't do anything. Note that `fetch` will "succeed" in some common scenarios where you might expect a failure, like if the status code is in the 400s...

Comment: @DanielBeck Hmm. Just use the catch() block. Hadn't thought of that. Thx